# ASP.NET Development API

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have created sites in Rails and Django and they both have a console where you could access the database, create new objects etc. :

```
# Django provides a rich database lookup API.
>>> Reporter.objects.get(id=1)
<Reporter: John Smith>
>>> Reporter.objects.get(full_name__startswith='John')
<Reporter: John Smith>
>>> Reporter.objects.get(full_name__contains='mith')
<Reporter: John Smith>
>>> Reporter.objects.get(id=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Is there any means to do this on ASP.net? It kind of sucks to have to put breakpoints into the program just to see what the current context of the site is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely familiar with Rails/Django, but have you tried the built-in Visual Studio Server Explorer? I'm assuming you're using VS and not Xamarin.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x603htbk.aspx

Comment: Express version, yeah. So that provides a simple database view, but I need to use SQL to do any sort of edit or complex views?

Comment: Not that I've ever found. You should be able to run SQL queries inline. Not sure about the Express version but you should be able to save the queries to re-run them if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will look into it. Either way its kind of a let down for the platform. Perhaps with the open sourcing of the compiler this will change.

Comment: Have you looked into the Locals window? From the "Debug" menu > "Windows" > "Locals"? That may help, too - and is invaluable as a developer in VS. Stepping through the code with breakpoints can be very helpful, too (putting a breakpoint somewhere and using F10 to step through code). It may not be the same thing but you can watch your objects in real time at least (and manipulate them).

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio immediate window and watch window